# limit %do %while iterations

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to run a while/until loop in a macro function, and have its maximum number of iterations limited. I found how to do it in 'usual' sas :

```
 data dataset;
    do i=1 to 10 until(condition);      /*10 iterations max */
        /* stuff */
    end;
 run;
```

but if I try it in a macro function :

```
 %macro mf;
 data dataset;
 %do i=1 %to 10 %until(nrow(X)>10);      /*10 iterations max */
 /* stuff */
 %end;
 run;
 %mend;

%mf;
```

I get these errors :

```
ERROR: Improper use of macro reserved word until.
ERROR: A dummy macro will be compiled.
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: 10 %until(nrow(X)>10)
ERROR: The %TO value of the %DO I loop is invalid.
ERROR: The macro MF will stop executing.
```

What is the proper way to limit loops iterations in macro-functions ?

Here is a data set in case you want to test ideas :

```
DATA dataset;
input X Y Z;
cards;
10 0 20
50 20 60
90 60 30
run;
```

Comment: Why use a macro `%DO %WHILE` loop *within* a datastep when it's designed to achieve the same result? By all means wrap your datastep in a macro to make it reusable, but in this example a regular `do while` loop is sufficient.

Comment: A google search for the terms "sas macro do until" yielded the reference page for `%do %until` as the first result: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543770.htm  It even comes complete with example code.  That's far fewer words you would have had to type and you would have received your answer much faster.  I love helping people who are stuck but please be sure you have done your own research before asking others to help.

Comment: @ChrisJ : this code is highly inspired of some hat I saw [here](http://web.utk.edu/sas/OnlineTutor/1.2/en/60476/m34/m34_27.htm). I just used it as example and don't use datastep in my own, which was far too complicated to be posted here.

Comment: @RobertPenridge : I actually searched a lot before posting here but got mislead by the combination of `to`and `until`posted above (I tried to generalize it to macro-sas unsuccessfully). Moreover, I used the keyword `while` rather than `until` and the sas documentation for `%do %while` don't show how to solve my problem. Supposing `while` and `until` would be similar, I figured I would find the same advices for both of them, so I didn't check the `%do %until` doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is an example of what you can use:

```
%macro mf;
  %let i=0;
  %do %until(&onechar=e or &i=10);
    %let i=%eval(&i+1);
    %let onechar=%substr(abcdefghij,&i,1);
  %end;
  %put onechar=&onechar;
  %put i=&i;
%mend mf;
%mf;
```

The macro loop stops if it finds "e" or i=10.